# How can I integrate Amazon Checkout into Spreecommerce?

Tags: spree, amazon-pay

We would like to integrate [Amazon Checkout](https://payments.amazon.com/business/html-button) into our Spreecommerce site.

I cannot find an extension for this, also because I am slightly confused about "Amazon FPS" vs. "Amazon Checkout" vs. "Amazon Simple Pay".

Is there a solution replicating the Paypal Express functionality for Amazon, allowing customers with an amazon account to pay via this account?

Comment: Unfortunately, Amazon Checkout is not supported by Spree, or Active Merchant (which is used within Spree to provide support for many gateways).  In order to get this working, you'll probably have to write a bunch of integration code.

Comment: That's sad news. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spree integration for Amazon's new Login and Pay service is available here:

https://github.com/amzn/spree_pay_with_amazon

Amazon FPS, Checkout and Simple Pay are older services.  The new platform offers all of the same features, but works more like a standard payment gateway.

Comment: Any plans for Amazon pay integration with Spree Commerce 4?

Answer (score 0):

We've relased an extension for Amazon FPS, available at https://github.com/AnnArborTees/spree_amazon_fps

It's been thoroughly tested against Spree 2-2-stable.